# How can I scale an overlay within an ffmpeg filtercomplex?

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, scaling, watermark

I would like to apply a PNG [overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#overlay) (watermark) to an arbitrary video file using ffmpeg. I would like the video to stay its original size (which I don't know ahead of time), and the PNG to be [scaled](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#scale) relative to the video.

For example, the following command places the overlay in the top left:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mov -i header.png -filter_complex \
    "[0][1] overlay=0:0" output.mkv
```

And the following command scales the overlay relative to itself (1/5 of the width, height relative):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mov -i header.png -filter_complex \
    "[1] scale=iw/5:-1 [scaled]; \
    [0][scaled] overlay=0:0" output.mkv
```

How could I make the overlay 1/5 of the width of `input.mov`? (For example, is it possible to store and/or query the width of another filter clause?)

The closest question I've come across is [Scale watermark overlay by video size with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/809820/scale-watermark-overlay-by-video-size-with-ffmpeg) but that answer uses external Linux/Cygwin commands. [FFmpeg watermark](https://superuser.com/questions/606080/ffmpeg-watermark) was also helpful while I was figuring ffmpeg out. However, I'm on Windows and invoking ffmpeg via Python, so I'd like to do it all within the filter_complex clause. If that's not possible, I'd like to know for sure so I can stop trying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be two separate commands, one to calculate the dimensions and another to overlay. You can simply use [`FFprobe`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) which comes alongside with [`FFmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html). To calculate the dimensions you can use the following command.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input_video
```

This will result like following.

> width=1280
>
> height=720

After you can do what ever the math you want and apply this to your overlay command.
Also [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg) are some more options for scaling.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?

Answer (score 1):

A much easier solution than using FFprobe and then "doing whatever math you want" is to simply use FFmpeg's built-in `scale2ref` filter, using the main video as a reference:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=5:H-h-5" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This example will make the logo 10% (i.e. 1/10th) the size of the main video, and comes courtesy of [llogan's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/1191147).